# ¿Cómo realizar un cluster jerárquico a partir de un listado de palabras con sus valores y diferentes relaciones?

Tags: python, cluster, hierarchical-clustering

Dispongo de un listado de palabras, 4200 exactamente. Cada palabra tiene un valor asociado, siendo la mayor 100, y el resto el valor porcentual relativo a este.

Además, cada palabra tiene unos enlaces salientes y otros entrantes. Se trata de un diccionario, donde cada palabra en su definición utiliza otras palabras (enlace saliente), y del mismo modo otras palabras utilizan esta palabra para definirse (enlace entrante).

Dispongo una matriz de 4200 x 4200, en la que, a simple vista, se sabe que palabras dependen de otras y así sucesivamente, ya que si una palabra utiliza a otra para definirse, esa casilla de la matriz es un 1, y si no la utiliza, es un 0.

Tanto la matriz como el listado de palabras con sus valores es el resultado que he obtenido de analizar un diccionario.

Lo que necesito ahora es tratar dichos datos y obtener el cluster jerárquico para obtener una pirámide de relaciones, observando los distintos grupos principales de palabras. No se si me explico.

A modo de ejemplo, pongo las primeras 10 palabras, con sus valores, y el número de enlaces entrantes y salientes (tenemos el número de enlaces, pero no a qué palabras van o de que palabras vienen esos enlaces, dato que si fuera necesario se extrae de la matriz comentada).

[image: Listado_10_primeras_palabras]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola @Miguel. Por favor, puedes poner el código de lo que has intentado?

Comment: Hola! No he intentado nada para el clustering, ya que no tengo la menor idea de por donde empezar. Podría enviarte el código analizando el diccionario y el modelo matemático aplicado para obtener el listado de palabras con sus valores, así como sus enlaces, y la matriz de relaciones, pero eso no importa en esto, ya que lo obtenido son datos de partida para el cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí correctamente, prueba un [dendrograma](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_agglomerative_dendrogram.html).

Comment: ¿Podrías ilustrar tu respuesta mostrando que resultado obtienes con la técnica propuesta? Un simple enlace no es de mucho valor.

Comment: Gracias. SIn embargo, no entiendo bien como tratarlo. Ya que si aplico un dendograma tan solo tiene en cuenta una variable, como por ejemplo, el valor de esa palabra. Sin embargo necesitaría también tener en cuenta las relaciones entre las palabras, para que la jerarquía fuera realista. No se si me explico. Salugos.